# Safari return 302 HTTP status code after form submit

Tags: apache, http, iframe, safari, http-headers

I have problem with form submit using **POST method** in Safari browsers. After form submit in Safari browser is returned Status Code 302 and redirect to **GET method**. Form is loaded as **iframe** on crossdomain page. In other browsers submit works fine (Status code is 200)

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

**Request headers:**

```
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```

**Response headers**

```
Date: Mon, 19 Aug 2013 13:47:56 GMT
p3p: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

**Form Data**

```
selectedDate:19.8.2013
selectedTimeString:19:00
```

Have anyone experience with this issue?

Web server: Apache Tomcat 5.5 + Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

It's because Safari blocks **third party** cookies in default configuration. Solution is to use URL to share sessionId.